# MVVM Binding a combobox

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I have a very ordinary ViewModel and I am tring to bind a collection of values to a combobox. The problem is nothing is binding. I have checked the ViewModel constructor and the data is being loaded so I suspect its in my XAML but I just cant find out where.

```
public class OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    readonly UserAccountContext _userAccountContext;
    readonly LoadOperation<Structure> _loadStructures;


    #region Properties

    private ObservableCollection<Structure> _structures;
    public ObservableCollection<Structure> Structures
    {
        get { return _structures; }

        set
        {
            _structures = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Structures");
        }
    }

    private Structure _selectedStructure;
    public Structure SelectedStructure
    {
        get { return _selectedStructure; }
        set
        {
            _selectedStructure = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStructure");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    public OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel()
    {
        _userAccountContext = new UserAccountContext();

        if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            _loadStructures = _userAccountContext.Load(_userAccountContext.GetStructuresQuery());
            _loadStructures.Completed += new EventHandler(_loadStructures_Completed);
        }
    }

    void _loadStructures_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
        foreach (var structure in _loadStructures.Entities)
        {
            Structures.Add(structure);
        }
    }
}

<UserControl.Resources>
    <viewmodel:OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel x:Key='ViewModel'></viewmodel:OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel>
</UserControl.Resources>

<ComboBox x:Name='cboApartments'
                          ItemsSource='{Binding Structures,Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Mode=TwoWay}'
                          Width='200' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this line:

```
 _structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
```

with this:

```
Structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
```

And set the binding of ComboBox to OneWay.

**Edited to update solution:**

Set DisplayMemberPath property of ComboBox as well:

```
DisplayMemberPath="StructureName"
```

Comment: Done ... made no difference unfortunately

Comment: Are you sure the event handler _loadStructures_Completed is called?
By the way, it seems you forgot to set DisplayMemberPath property of the ComboBox.

Comment: Everything in the viewmodel is working as expected. The structures are populating the Structure property correctly. The issue MUST be with the XAML ???

Comment: DisplayMemberPath must be set as DisplayMemberPath = StructureName

Comment: DisplayMemberPath='{Binding StructureName}'

Comment: That's not the correct syntax. You should use like this: DisplayMemberPath="StructureName". You can reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath(VS.95).aspx)

Comment: Hi Quang - THANKS , its finally working. I also had to change the order of the Load.Completed to the last call in the constructor and it started working.

Comment: Hi Quang - I am now having trouble setting the selecteditem of the combobox once the ViewModel constructor has run. I set the viewmodels SelectedStructure property but the combo doesntg set its value. Any ideas?

Comment: You should use TwoWay binding:

SelectedItem='{Binding SelectedStructure,Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Mode=TwoWay}'

Answer (score 2):

Try intializing your ObservableCollection of Structures like that:

```
void _loadStructures_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>(_loadStructures.Entities);      
    }
```

and as it was mentioned earlier i think you should change order here:

```
if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
{
    //other code before
    //_loadStructures = ...
    _loadStructures.Completed += new EventHandler(_loadStructures_Completed);
   //and now start loading       
}
```

I did similar, very simple app to check what could gone wrong, but everything works well. I will show you my code, so you can compare and maybe you will find some bugs in your solution.

Structure.cs

```
public class Structure
{
    public Structure(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

StructureService.cs

```
public class StructureService
{
    public void GetAllStructures(Action<IList<Structure>> CompleteCallback)
    {
        var temp = new List<Structure>() 
            {
                new Structure("Str1"),
                new Structure("Str2"),
                new Structure("Str3"),
                new Structure("Str4"),
                new Structure("Str5"),
                new Structure("Str6"),
                new Structure("Str7")
            };
        CompleteCallback(temp);
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
    {
        var temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel:

```
public class OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    StructureService service;
    public OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel()
    {
        if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
        {
            service = new StructureService();
            service.GetAllStructures((result) =>
            {
                Structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>(result);
            });

        }
    }
    private ObservableCollection<Structure> _structures;
    public ObservableCollection<Structure> Structures
    {
        get { return _structures; }
        set
        {
            _structures = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Stuctures");
        }
    }
    private Structure _selectedStructure;
    public Structure SelectedStructure
    {
        get { return _selectedStructure; }
        set
        {
            _selectedStructure = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedStructure");
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboApartments"
                          ItemsSource='{Binding Structures,Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Mode=TwoWay}'
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStructure, Source={StaticResource ViewModel},Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Width="100" Height="30">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

If i were in your shoes i wll change xaml to such view:

SuggestedView:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <ComboBox x:Name="cboApartments"
                          ItemsSource='{Binding Structures, Mode=TwoWay}'
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStructure, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Width="100" Height="30">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

but i understand that it is somehow impossible in your scenario?
[image]

Comment: I changed the order and an exception was thrown {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GateBlox.ViewModels.OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel..ctor()}

Comment: I dont understand why the order of these 2 line of code makes a difference. Anybody got an explanation?

Comment: By changing order i mean that in first order you should subscribe for Completed event, and then start async loading operation, because in other way it could happen that Completed event occurs before you subscribe for this event. In my code it should be some other code before _loadStructures.Completed += new EventHandler(_loadStructures_Completed); but i don't know how it could be done in your code.

Comment: I analyzed very deeply your app, and i'm sure that xaml is OK. Adding items to ObservableCollection is also without mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the effort everyone is putting in. PawelSt : I copied your Combobox XAML - no difference.

Comment: PawelSt - I copied your code and I have a question. How come you do not refer to the ViewModel source in your combobox? ie source={StaticResource ViewModel}

Comment: I am convinced now that the error has to be linked in some way to the LoadEvent.Completed. The error I am getting refers to a problem with the constructor:The invocation of the constructor on type 'GateBlox.ViewModels.OwnerOccupierAccountViewModel' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception. [Line: 12 Position: 56]

Comment: I assume that your previous question reffers to my SuggestedView. So, not reffering to the source each time when i'm binding is possible becouse of setting earlier DataContext property for UserControl. When this property is set, then all children inherit this property and it is default source for binding.

Comment: Ah OK - I havent set the DataContext in th XAML

Comment: Sorry Pawel, one more question. I am having trouble getting the combobox to bind to the value from the SelectedStructure property in the ViewModel. I have exactly the same code as you ... SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedStructure, Mode=TwoWay} ... any ideas?

Comment: If DataContext is setted properly and you are using SL4 i don't where the problem could be.

Answer (score 1):

The binding will only fire when the property is changed. The line setting the backing variable won't call the RaisePropertyChanged event. Even if it did it would be empty at this point anyway and you'd end up with an empty list.

```
_structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
```

When you then add to the collection you aren't changing the property value, you're calling the getter so again the RaisePropertyChanged won't fire.

```
Structures.Add(structure);
```

You need to build a local collection then use that as the value for the Structures property. This should cause the binding to be triggered.

```
var structures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
foreach ...
Structures = structures;
```

Comment: changed the code - still not binding    void _loadStructures_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var theseStructures = new ObservableCollection<Structure>();
            foreach (var structure in _loadStructures.Entities)
            {
                theseStructures.Add(structure);
            }

            Structures = theseStructures;
        }

Comment: The Structures collection is correctly populated when the method is completed. The debugger is showing the Structures property set with 3 structures which is correct. The problem must be with the XAML binding.

Comment: I've created a dummy app using your code and having to guess some items (ViewModelBase, Structure) the issue appears to be with DisplayMemberPath as mentioned by Quang Vo. As soon as I set it to the property I want displayed (Name in my case) it works. DisplayMemberPath="Name". I still think what I have said is correct but don't think I should get the credit for the display member path catch.

Comment: To add using a data template as shown by PawelSt would also do the job.

Comment: Been offline for a few days glad to see you got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding directly to the ViewModel key as a source, but is it set as a DataContext anywhere?

Comment: Hi Joel = No, the DataContext is not explicitly set anywhere.